# Terraform project to create VPC/IGW, VPN, and private subnet with NATGW - Connectivity Analyzer says no route from NATGW to IGW

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws

https://github.com/phillhocking/aws-network-vpn/tree/1000

I have been trying to figure this out for quite some time, and I really am struggling at understanding why these components can't talk to each other. The VPC has an IGW which is necessary for an EIP for the NATGW, however, nothing on this subnet can get out to the public internet. Everything works fine over the VPN link, but the Connectivity Analyzer indicates there's no connectivity between the NATGW and the IGW as there is not a route - how would I route just the NATGW traffic to the IGW without something like a 0.0.0.0/0 route which already is assigned to the NATGW for this subnet?

[Connectivity Analyzer - Route Table has no route to IGW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgwF7.png)

I know I am just missing something bonehead simple. Look at the repo for how the whole thing goes together, but here's the VPC module:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block            = var.cidr_block
  enable_dns_hostnames  = true
  enable_dns_support    = true

  tags = {
    Name = var.vpc_name
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "dev" {
  count = var.subnet_count
  # This line is necessary to ensure that we pick availabiltiy zones that can launch any size ec2 instance
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(var.cidr_block, 6, count.index * 2 + 1)


  tags = {
    Name = "dev-subnet-${count.index}"
  }
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "dev" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  subnet_ids = aws_subnet.dev[*].id

  ingress {
    protocol   = -1
    rule_no    = 1000
    action     = "allow"
    #cidr_block = var.prem_network_address_space
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    from_port  = 0
    to_port    = 0
  }

  egress {
    protocol   = -1
    rule_no    = 100
    action     = "allow"
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    from_port  = 0
    to_port    = 0
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "dev-acl"
  }
}

# Gateways

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.vpc_name}-internet-gateway"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "nat-gw" {
  vpc = true

  tags = {
    Name = "nat-elastic-ip"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.gw]
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "gw" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat-gw.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.dev[0].id

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.vpc_name}-nat-gateway-dev"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.gw]
}

# VPC Route Table

resource "aws_default_route_table" "default" {
  default_route_table_id = aws_vpc.main.main_route_table_id

    route {
      cidr_block    = "0.0.0.0/0"
      gateway_id    = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
    }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.vpc_name}-public"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.gw]
}

# dev Subnet Route Table

resource "aws_route_table" "dev" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  tags = {
    Name = "dev-route-table"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "dev_routes" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.dev[0].id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.dev.id

  depends_on = [aws_nat_gateway.gw]
}

resource "aws_route" "dev_nat" {
  route_table_id            = aws_route_table.dev.id
  destination_cidr_block    = "0.0.0.0/0"
  nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.gw.id

  depends_on = [aws_nat_gateway.gw]
```

Comment: Looks like the mistake I was making was that I did not have a 'public' subnet to launch the nat gateway into. Sure would have been great if whoever downvoted me let me know lol.

Answer (score 1):

You are placing NAT in `aws_subnet.dev[0]`, then you create `aws_route_table.dev` that you attach to the subnet. What's more the `aws_route_table.dev` has a route `aws_route.dev_nat` which points to the NAT.

So basically you are doing some **circular routing** - all traffic in `aws_subnet.dev[0]` is direct to NAT in the same subnet, which in turn is directed again to the same NAT.

As you pointed in comment, NAT should be in **public subnet**, while subnet directing traffic to NAT should be private subnets.